# How to handle local modifications that shall be persisted, but not pushed to repostory?

Tags: git

Let's draw the following scenario: A team of 3 developers hare a bare repository. Devs want to share a `config.ini` file, which they can locally adapt (e.g. database connection parameters).

One could

1. create file locally,
2. add, commit and push file to remote repository,
3. then modify file,
4. perform `git update-index --assume-unchanged config.ini`

A `git status` now would return `nothing to commit, working directory clean`

But as soon as I would do a `git checkout -f` (e.g. if I want to clean my working area), my local modifications would get lost.

What does git offer to handle such a `config.ini` in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Create a template for you configuration file and checkin that file. Something like

`config.ini.template`.

Add `config.ini` to `.gitignore`

Comment: Do I have to copy the content from `config.ini.template` to `config.ini` each time I do `git checkout -f`?

Comment: No. You will have to do it the very first time you clone the repository. After that, whatever changes you make to config.ini will be ignored by git.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem for the creator of the file itself.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel, why so? The creator is no different from the rest of the devs: \[s\]he just creates `config.ini.template` and copies it to their local version -- `config.ini`. That is, the "reference" file is always the template, not the original, hence only the template is added to the repository and all updates go to it, not to the actual *untracked* configuration file each developer maintains separately.

Comment: Ah, now I understand how you mean it. But the `config.ini` itself is a required file in the remote repository as that is pushed to a running deployment.

Comment: you will have to make your deploy script to copy config.ini.template as config.ini